# Does an uppercase property auto-create a lowercase private property in C#?

Tags: c#, properties

Take this code:

```
public int Foo {get;set;}
```

As opposed to this more complete manually written code:

```
private int x;
public int X 
{
    get { return x; }
    set { x = value; }
}
```

In the first example, does the compiler *automatically create* a `private` `foo` property?

I am not sure if this convention I have seen of having a *lowercase* `private` property masked by a `public`-facing *uppercase* one is just that, convention, or if it's actually part of the language/compiler, and you can either write it out or let it be done for you.

Comment: Furthering Him, `{get;set;}` and `public int X => 10` are just syntactic sugar

Comment: public Properties should always start with an uppercase letter and private fields should always start with an underscore

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why not just have a look what's going on?

```
  public class Test {
    // private int myProp;

    public int MyProp {
      get;
      set;
    }
  }
```

...

```
  string report = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, typeof(Test)
    .GetFields(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance)
    .Select(field => field.Name));

  Console.Write(report);
```

And you'll get quite a weird name

> `<MyProp>k__BackingField`

however this strange backing field name ensures that there'll be no *name conflict* (you can't declare any field, property, method etc. starting with `<`).

**Edit:** if you *uncomment* `// private int myProp;` line you'll have

> ```
> myProp
> <MyProp>k__BackingField
> ```

please, notice that `myProp` *is not* a backing field for the `MyProp` property.

Comment: So in my second example, the properties `x` and `X` are only related because the implementation specifies that it is so, not because of any inherent property of C#? If `X` were simply `{ get; set; }` then they would be two unrelated properties?

Comment: @Aerovistae: you're quite right: you'll have *field* `x` unrelated to *property* `X`; and property `X` will have its own *backing field* with that strange autogenerated name.

Answer (score 5):

The casing has nothing to do with it.

Writing a property like below

```
public int x { get; set; }
```

will always create and use an anonymous private field which it manipulates via `get`/`set`.

Comment: "Like below" . . . do you mean anytime you don't fill out the getter and setter functions, and only write `get;` and `set;` ? What if you fill out one but not the other?

Comment: @Aerovistae Try it out. The compiler won´t allow that

Comment: Writing `public int x { get; }` will have the difference that it creates a `readonly` field, rather than a normal one.

Comment: But what if you write `{get; set { Console.WriteLn("Testing"); }`

Comment: @Aerovistae Try it out, as allready mentioned. Produces compiler-error, it is not possible to create only one part of an auto-generated property whilst implementing the other one.

Comment: Ah, I see. But you can provide an implementation for `get` only, so long as you omit `set` altogether, because it's read-only.

Comment: Thank you! One last question, what is this syntax called, where there's an assignment after the get/set? So that I can google it. `public List<Tracker> Trackers { get; } = new List<Tracker>();`

Comment: @Aerovistae that is called a "property initializer", which is a feature introduced in C# 6.0 (before that you could only initialize a field like that on declaration, but not properties)

Answer (score 2):

The compiler does create a private backing-field of the desired type for you, however with another name (it´s not simply `x` as in your example, it´s more something like `<X>_BackingField`). Thus you can´t access the field. However the actual syntax is quite similar.

Have a further look at [auto-generated properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb384054.aspx):

> the compiler creates a private, anonymous backing field that can only be accessed through the property's get and set accessors.

Having said this the two code-samples within your question are identical in their meaning.